# Почему powerShell не присваивает переменную в teamCity?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Я только изучаю тим сити и наткнулся на крайне не понятую проблему. У меня есть в проекте  env.versionReleas, которая должна получать значение от скрипта PowerShell. Делаю как в доках, но результат не как в доках. Скрипт простой:

```
$sss="afaf"
Write-Host "##teamcity[versionReleas name='env.versionReleas' value='$sss']"
```

но переменная как и была пустая, так такой и остается.
Настройки переменной ничего не дали, тим сити, словно игнорирует мой запрос. У кого нибудь такое было? Другие вопросы не решают данную проблему.

TeamCity: 2021.1.1 (build 92714)

Answer (score 1):

Правильный синтаксис должен быть такой:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.versionReleas' value='$sss']"
```

Comment: К сожалению, данное решение не помогло. Переменная все также пуста

Comment: @Deadmyself Попробуйте вывести значение прям в этом же скрипте. Посмотрите не появляются ли специальные символы внутри `$sss`, например `'`, ']'. Есть ли ошибки в логе? Попробуйте вместо переменной окружения (c префиксом `env.`) использовать обычную. В моих скриптах я работал только с обычной.

Comment: увы, но смена типа на параметра ничего не дало, в билд логе все хорошо, специальных символов нет. Я уже не знаю что думать.

Comment: @Deadmyself я бы создал новый билд с нуля, с одним только скриптом, ну не может же оно совсем не работать. так же бы попробовал обычный cmd скрипт, не павершел